# Degree of Separation with Facebook API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to fetch degree of separation between users in Facebook API. Similar to the one in LinkedIn. I tried to fetch friends of friends through the Facebook API v2.2, but it didn't work out.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Please try to be a lot more specific: What do you mean by "it didn't work out". What have you tried? How did the outcome differ from what you hoped for?

Comment: @reto i mean the facebook api allows me to access the friendlist of people who are using the app only, which makes things hard for me to achieve my task....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"it did not work out" is not a good description. But anyway, what you are trying to achieve is not possible at all. You can´t get access to "friends of friends", you can´t even get access to "all friends" (first level) anymore. With [/me/friends](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.2/user/friends), you only get friends who authorized your App too, for privacy reasons.

See the changelog for more information: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Is there any possibility with page scraping?

Comment: scraping is not allowed according to the facebook terms. and there would be no possibility for this anyway, you can´t check if someone is your friend or not - and that´s only one of the problems.